# Open file in bash script

Tags: bash, file-io, parentheses

I've got a bash script accepting several files as input which are mixed with various script's options, for example:

```
bristat -p log1.log -m lo2.log log3.log -u
```

I created an array where i save all the index where i can find files in the script's call, so in this case it would be an arrat of 3 elements where

```
arr_pos[0] = 2
arr_pos[1] = 4
arr_pos[3] = 5
```

Later in the script I must call "head" and "grep" in those files and i tried this way

```
head -n 1 ${arr_pos[0]}
```

but i get this error non runtime

```
head: cannot open `2' for reading: No such file or directory
```

I tried various parenthesis combinations, but I can't find which one is correct.

Comment: perhaps you are trying to access the second argument by somehow with double substitution. you can check about `shift` http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_09_07.html

Comment: @abasu i know the standard method for getting an argument from the script's call ($X where X is the position of the argument) but this doesn't work..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that `${arr_pos[0]}` stores the index in which you have the file name, not the file name itself -- so you can't simply `head` it. The array storing your arguments is given by `$@`.

A possible way to access the data you want is:

```
#! /bin/bash

declare -a arr_pos=(2 4 5)
echo ${@:${arr_pos[0]}:1}
```

Output:

```
log1.log
```

The expansion `${@:${arr_pos[0]}:1}` means you're taking the values ranging from the index `${arr_pos[0]}` in the array `$@`, to the element of index `${arr_pos[0]} + 1` in the same array `$@`.

Another way to do so, as pointed by @flaschenpost, is to `eval` the index preceded by `$`, so that you'd be accessing the array of arguments. Although it works very well, it may be risky depending on who is going to run your script -- as they may add commands in the argument line.

Anyway, you may should try to loop through the entire array of arguments by the beginning of the script, *hashing* the values you find, so that you won't be in trouble while trying to fetch each value later. You may loop, using a `for + case ... esac`, and store the values in associative arrays.

Comment: ${@:${arr_pos[0]}:1} 1 what stands for?
If I'm right, i'm trying to "reach" the ${arr_pos[0]} element in scrip's call ( ${@:...} )

Comment: @ArrigoPierotti I've added an explanation to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think eval is what you need.

```
#!/bin/bash

arr_pos[0]=2;
arr_pos[1]=4;
arr_pos[2]=5;

eval "cat \$${arr_pos[1]}"
```

For me that works.